# Google Play Games Services API returns "Internal server error"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-games

This page: https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players/get

I'm using "Try it" to test, but get "500 Internal Server Error".

Calling this API by curl or the tool on the website.